# Select2, select a text if no results available

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use Select2 to obtain dropdown results from database:

```
$("#loadingdata").select2({
    placeholder: "3 characters to go",
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "ajax_cats.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) { // page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
        return {
        q: term //search term           
        };
        },
        results: function (data) {
        //var more = (page * 10) < data.total; // whether or not there are more results available

        // notice we return the value of more so Select2 knows if more results can be loaded
        return {results: data};
        }                       
    },  

    // user can select value
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {
                return {id:term, text:term};
            }
        },

    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller        
});
```

User can select typed value, but ONLY if more results exist in database.

**Is there a way to click to add typed value in search box when no results are available from the database?**

Comment: Is the `createSearchChoice` not working for you? Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting tags:true when initializing the select box, that will temporarily add the typed value to the list